# How to remove "triangle" line from GraphicsComplex objects

Tags: graphics3d

Code follows:

```
partsName = {
  "1.stl", "2.stl", "3.stl", "4.stl", "5.stl", "6.stl", "7.stl", "8.stl", "9.stl"
}; 

robotPartsGraphics = Import[#, "GraphicsComplex"] & /@ partsName;

Graphics3D[{robotPartsGraphics}]
```

[image]

and now, I want to remove the "triangle" line from the picture. What can I do?
(Comment: CAD product, format "stl" -> contains `GraphicsComplex` data.

I appreciate **Szabolcs**'s and 
**Kuba**'s advice, all can work successfully! add `EdgeForm[None]` in last code sentence. The successful code is: `Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], robotPartsGraphics}]`.

Thank you again!

[image]

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "triangle line".  Try `Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], robotPartsGraphics}]`

Comment: Thank you very much! i means the "connect line" in function "graphicscomplex ", like the black connect line in picture

Comment: Can you respond to my suggestion above to confirm if I understood your question?

Comment: EdgeForm[None] can work successfully! thank you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None],
  Import["ExampleData/seashell.stl", "GraphicsComplex"]
  }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: EdgeForm@None can work successfully! you code is more concise than me! thank you very much !

Comment: `EdgeForm[]` works as well.