# How to make object to be transparent?

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, opacity

code follows

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None],
  Import["ExampleData/seashell.stl", "GraphicsComplex"]
  }
 ]
```

can i make the seashell to be transparent?

example from [How to remove “triangle” line from GraphicsComplex objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/154823/how-to-remove-triangle-line-from-graphicscomplex-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official documents,[`Opacity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Opacity.html) works.

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], Opacity[0.5], 
  Import["ExampleData/seashell.stl", "GraphicsComplex"]}]
```